# Play video without display

Tags: android, video, audio

I want to play the audio of a video file without video display. Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a MediaPlayer. It doesn't show anything without you specifically coding it.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to play it for just 10 sec. How to control it?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question so others will see it. Other people on here will be able to give you a much better answer than I could